# Find all the rational values of $x$ at which $y=\sqrt{x^2+x+3}$ is a rational number

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Question**

Find all the rational values of $x$ at which $y=\sqrt{x^2+x+3}$

**My attempt**

Since we only have to find the rational values of $x$ and $y$, we can assume that 
$$ x \in Q$$
$$ y \in Q$$
$$ y-x \in Q $$
Let$$ d = y-x$$
$$d=\sqrt{x^2+x+3}-x$$
$$d+x=\sqrt{x^2+x+3}$$
$$(d+x)^2=(\sqrt{x^2+x+3})^2$$
$$d^2 + x^2 + 2dx =x^2+x+3$$
$$d^2 +2dx = x +3$$
$$x = \frac{3-d^2}{2d-1}$$

$$d \neq \frac{1}{2}$$

So $x$ will be rational as long as $d \neq \frac{1}{2}$.

Now
$$ y = \sqrt{x^2+x+3}$$
$$ y = \sqrt{(\frac{3-d^2}{2d-1})^2 + \frac{3-d^2}{2d-1} + 3}$$
$$ y = \sqrt{\frac{(3-d^2)^2}{(2d-1)^2} + \frac{(3-d^2)(2d-1)}{(2d-1)^2} + 3\frac{(2d-1)^2}{(2d-1)^2}}$$
$$ y = \sqrt{\frac{(3-d^2)^2 + (3-d^2)(2d-1) + 3(2d-1)^2}{(2d-1)^2}} $$
$$ y = \frac{\sqrt{(3-d^2)^2 + (3-d^2)(2d-1) + 3(2d-1)^2}}{(2d-1)}$$
$$ y = \frac{\sqrt{d^4-2d^3+7d^2-6d+9}}{(2d-1)}$$

I know that again $d \neq \frac{1}{2}$ but I don't know what to do with the numerator. Help

Comment: Just by inspection, $x=2$ and $x=-3$ work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

The expression is of the following form 
$$(a+b-c)^2 = a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab-2bc-2ac$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the numerator will be $(d^2-d+3)^2$

Comment: And how do we see this? Thanks +1

Comment: just looking for a quadratic form as we need to get rid of the square root. Obviously $x^2$ and $3^2$ will be a part of the expression so it was just a matter of time to figure out that the third term is $-x$

Comment: Thanks, you actually mean $d$ right.

Comment: Yes, of course  :) I updated the answer, just when I worked on the problem I wrote it in terms of $x$